# Sending server messages with google - account suspended

Tags: devise, smtp

While manually testing our app we found that the server does not send 
emails anymore (using SMTP).

It was because Google has suspended our account:

"This user has been suspended for abuse."

What are the limitation on sending emails and how can we overcome them?
Is there any other SMTP provider that we can use without restriction?

We're using Devise over a Ubuntu server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this:

http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22839